# Properties of Stratonovich and Ito integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I'm struggling to understand if I have this idea of an orthogonal transform (to simplify a set of SDE's in Ito form) understood. Suppose I have the orthogonal transform
\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  W_3^\star \\
  W_4^\star
 \end{bmatrix}
  = \int_{0}^{z}\begin{bmatrix}
   D_2^s & D_2^c \\
   -D_2^c & D_2^s
  \end{bmatrix}
   d\begin{bmatrix}
   W_3 \\
   W_4
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 (D_2^s)^2+(D_2^c)^2 = 1, \quad \begin{bmatrix}
  D_2^s,D_2^c
 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}
  -D_2^c,D_2^s
 \end{bmatrix}
 =0,
\end{align}

I believe I need to show that the variance and correlation are zero for the transform to hold? So if we consider the stochastic integral
\begin{align}\nonumber
 \mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}X(z)dW\bigg)\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}Y(z)dW\bigg)\bigg] &= \mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\sum_{i}X(z_i)\Delta W_i\bigg)\bigg(\sum_j Y(z_j)\Delta W_j\bigg)\bigg] \\ \nonumber
 &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[X(z_1)\Delta W_1\bigg(Y(z_1)\Delta W_1 + Y(z_2)\Delta W_2 + ...\bigg) \\ \nonumber
 &+X(z_2)\Delta W_2\bigg(...\bigg) +...\bigg] \\ \nonumber
 &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_i X(z_i)Y(z_i)(\Delta W_i)^2\bigg] \\ \nonumber
 &=\sum_i\mathbb{E}\bigg[X(z_i)Y(z_i)(\Delta W_i)^2\bigg] \\ \nonumber
 &= \sum_i\mathbb{E}\bigg[X(z_i)Y(z_i)\bigg](z_{i+1}-z_i) \\ \nonumber
 &= \mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_i X(z_i)Y(z_i)(z_{i+1}-z_i)\bigg] \\
 &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{a}^{b}X(z)Y(z)dz\bigg].
\end{align}
For two independent Wiener processes
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[W_1W_2] = 0.
\end{align}
This implies that
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}X(z)dW_1\bigg)\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}Y(z)dW_2\bigg)\bigg] = 0.
\end{align}
Furthermore...
\begin{align}\nonumber
 \mathbb{E}[W_3^\star W_4^\star] &= \mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{s}dW_3 + D_2^cdW_4\bigg)\bigg(\int_{0}^{x_3}D_2^sdW_4 - D_2^cdW_3\bigg)\bigg] \\ \nonumber 
 &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{s}dW_3\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_4 - \int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_4\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_3 \\ \nonumber
  &+ \int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_4\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{s}dW_4 - \int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_3\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{s}dW_3\bigg] \\ \nonumber
 &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_4\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{s}dW_4 - \int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{c}dW_3\int_{0}^{x_3}D_{2}^{s}dW_3\bigg] \\ \nonumber
 &=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{0}^{z}D_{2}^{c}D_{2}^{s}dz - \int_{0}^{z}D_{2}^{c}D_{2}^{s}dz\bigg] \\
 &=0.
\end{align}

Now my question is, would the transform work on a set of Stratonovich SDE's? I.e. would the transform

\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  W_3^\star \\
  W_4^\star
 \end{bmatrix}
  = \int_{0}^{x_3}\begin{bmatrix}
   D_2^s & D_2^c \\
   -D_2^c & D_2^s
  \end{bmatrix}
  \circ d\begin{bmatrix}
   W_3 \\
   W_4
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
be justified? Could someone give me some help if I can apply the same tests, but change to Stratonovich integral? Thanks if you made it this far...

Comment: What do you mean by "would the transform be justified"? You can define whatever you want. Clearly it's not going to have the same properties as the one with Ito integrals.